# Applying IntersectionObserver to multiple elements

Tags: javascript

This JS will lazy load certain elements in the corresponding HTML using the IntersectionObserver API.

```
class LazyElement {
  constructor(selectorClassName, callback) {
    this.target = document.querySelector(selectorClassName);
    this.callback = callback;
    this.isLoaded = false;
  }
}

const lazyElements = [
  new LazyElement('.youtube-video-container', callbackYoutube),
  new LazyElement('.cta', callbackCta)
]

const elementToLazyElement = new WeakMap()
lazyElements.forEach(function(lazyElement) {
  if (lazyElement.target) {
    elementToLazyElement.set(lazyElement.target, lazyElement)
  }
})

function callback(entries) {
  const lazyElement = elementToLazyElement.get(entries[0].target)
  if (lazyElement.isLoaded === false) {
    entries.forEach(function(entry) {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        lazyElement.callback(lazyElement)
        lazyElement.isLoaded = true;
      }
    })
  }
}

function callbackYoutube(lazyElement) {
  const youtubeContainer = $('.youtube-video-container')
  const id = youtubeContainer.attr('data-embed')
  const video = `<iframe src=${"https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + id} allowfullscreen></iframe>`;
  youtubeContainer.parent().html(video);
}

function callbackCta(lazyElement) {
  lazyElement.target.classList.add('cta-image')
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  lazyElements.forEach(function(lazyElement) {
    if (lazyElement.target) {
      let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback)
      observer.observe(lazyElement.target)
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: This is a code review forum, there is no question.

Comment: Okay, good luck